# is changing the html structure with jquery workable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title></title>
  <script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
   
</head>
<body>

<form action=" " method="post">
<input id="myInput" type="text"/>
<input id="myButton" type="button" value="submit"/>
<p id="myOutput" style="color: yellow; background: black; width: 100px;"></p>
</form>
<script>
    $("#myButton").click(function() {
        var data = $("#myInput").val();
        $("#myOutput").val(data);
    });
</script>
</body>
```

Let's say at the moment my code is

`<p id="myOutput" style="color: yellow; background: black; width: 100px;"></p>`

Is jQuery able to change the codes?

let's say if somehow I type red then the code would be

`<p id="myOutput" style="color: red; background: black; width: 100px;"></p>`

and if I have another input text area and input 200 then the code would be

`<p id="myOutput" style="color: yellow; background: black; width: 200px;"></p>`
something like that.

Not exactly want to change just the class or just the style or the width but just wondering if I can use a text area input and after submitting then maybe the value of the code would change something like that...

Comment: Can you use jQuery to modify the css of an element based on the value of an input? Yes.

Comment: [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css)

Comment: Yes you can. Use .css() function to achieve it. Read the documentation here http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: ah..I wasn't thinking of just css I'm thinking of something more complicated but just don't have any codes in my mind so I thought some simple code like this might answer me..really sorry my bad. I guess I should have what's in my first.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you mainly can manipulate all your HTML Code with JQuery.

**For Setting a value**

`$( '#myOutput' ).css( "color", "red" );`

**For getting a value**

```
$( '#myOutput' ).css( "color");
```

http://api.jquery.com/css/